# Redirect routes to separate controllers for same url pattern?

Tags: php, laravel

In my routes file "web.php", I'm having below routes.

```
//Backend Routes
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth', 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/leads', [AllLeadsController::class],'index')->name('web-leads');
    Route::resource('/news', NewsController::class);
    Route::resource('/page', PageController::class);
    Route::resource('/services', ServicesController::class);
    Route::resource('/blog', BlogController::class);
    Route::resource('/main-menu',MainMenuController::class);
});

Route::get('/{slug}', [PageController::class, 'getPage'])->where('slug', '([A-Za-z0-9\-\/]+)')->name('link_view');
```

I'm trying to access pages with **domainname.in/{slug}** and dashboard with **domainname.in/dashboard** pattern but dashboard prefix routes are redirecting to PageController instead of dashboard controller.

I tried where clause as below but still dashboard routes mapping to PageController.

```
Route::get('/{slug}', [PageController::class, 'getPage'])->where(['slug','!=','login'],['slug','!=','dashboard'],['slug','=','([A-Za-z0-9\-\/]+)'])->name('link_view');
```

Please suggest a solution to the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Routes you can only use one where condition. So you have to make one regular expression to include all conditions.

Or you can just have `dashboard` and `login` routes before universal `{slug}`.
For example:

```
Route::get('/login', [...]);
Route::get('/dashboard', [...]);
Route::get('/{slug}', [PageController::class, 'getPage'])->name('link_view');
```

Comment: Ok, whenever url calls dashboard, it redirecting to login page. I added new route `Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class,'index'])->name('login');` above the universal route and it worked. Thanks :)